# Is multithreading dangerous in sockets writing?

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcpclient

I'm creating a **network protocol** based on **Tcp**, and i am using **berkeley socket** via C#.
is the socket buffer gonna mixed up when two threads trying to send data via **socket.send** method at a time?
should i use **lock** for accessing one thread at a time?

Comment: Is this socket an unidirectional data stream from server to client?

Comment: Is this protocol based on requests and responses?

Comment: well, my protocol is base on this rule. [start][message size][message itself][end].and yes it's a client server. but what's the deal with it? i don't see any different between client server or server to server or client to client for this solution.

Comment: there is no need to be a request response. it's just sends data.it's for an online game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#thread-safety), the Socket class is thread safe. So, that means you don't need to lock the `send` method and you can safely send and receive on different threads. But be aware that the order is not guaranteed, so the data won't be mixed if you send it all at a single call to the `send` method instead of chuncked calls.

In addition to that, I would recommend to lock and flush it just in case you don't want the server swapping the responses across multiple concurrent requests. But that doesn't seems to be this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot, sometimes i forget to read from resources by myself. for locking, yes i have to lock. cause of ordering sending messages in order.